# Haar measure on Lie Group is unique

Tags: measure-theory, lie-groups, haar-measure

My question is

> Why is the Haar measure on a Lie Group unique upto scalar multiple?

I know how to show it for $\mathbb R^n$ because there I have countable many open balls that form a base and the measure of the unit ball around 0 gives the constant scalar.

How to show for general Lie Group?

Comment: Calm down. The left and [right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure#The_right_Haar_measure) Haar measures on a locally compact topological group are unique. See [here](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Gleason.pdf) for a proof.

Comment: What you said certainly is true. But I wanted a proof specifically for Lie Groups. The point is to show existence of Haar measure on Lie Group you can do it in a much easier way than for a general Topological group. I wanted to know if there's a way to show uniqueness easily too.

Comment: Choosing a coordinate chart around the identity, then the approach you use in $\mathbb{R}^n$ should work fine on a general Lie group.

Comment: @Angry_Math_Person A locally compact is far from being a "general topological group". Many interesting usual topological groups are not locally compact (infinite-dimensional normed spaces, many automorphism groups...)

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mu,\nu$ be two left Haar measures on a locally compact group. Then $\mu+\nu$ is a left Haar measure, and $\mu$ has a density $f$ with respect to it. Then $f$ is left-invariant, so is constant. Hence $\mu$ is a scalar multiple of $\mu+\nu$.

I don't really see how to make it simpler, even with additional assumptions?

Comment: Nice argument. I don't remember seeing that in textbook treatments.

Comment: I am missing something I believe. What is the reason that $\mu$ has a density $f$ with respect to $\mu + \nu$? And why doesn't the same reason not tell you more directly that it has a density w.r.t $\nu$?

Comment: Because $\mu\ll\mu+\nu$, so $\mu$ has a density with respect to $\mu+\nu$ by the [Radon-Nikodym theorem] (I should have assumed the group $\sigma$-compact to ensure that the measure are $\sigma$-finite, i.e., for Lie groups, that the number of components is countable. In general we don't know a priori that $\mu\ll\nu$. (Recall that $\mu_1\ll\mu_2$ means that $\mu_2(A)=0$ implies $\mu_1(A)=0$: one says that $\mu_1$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu_2$).

Comment: @YCor Thanks! That clarifies it!

Comment: Why is the density f left invariant?

Comment: It's straightforward that it's left-invariant modulo measure zero ($gf-f$ is a.e. zero for each given $g$). Some argument to show it's indeed constant modulo measure zero should indeed be added.

Comment: @YCor btw I asked a question about that last step [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4393390/if-g-acts-transitively-on-x-and-a-function-f-on-x-is-g-invariant-up-t?noredirect=1&lq=1).